# In .htaccess, can I pass on "OPTIONS *" to be handled by PHP?

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

I have a `RewriteRule .* index.php` to catch everything

Everything else seems to pass through just fine, even `OPTIONS /`. But Apache doesn't seem to let me handle `OPTIONS *`, and in fact just returns a blank 200 OK without even including an Allow header.

```
% curl -X OPTIONS http://localhost:8080 -i -v --request-target "*"
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.88.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 06 Jul 2023 00:25:39 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.57 (Unix) PHP/8.2.7
< Content-Length: 0

<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Does anyone have any clue whether it's even possible, and if so how to let the asterisk option through, or even just somehow identify it so I can have it reply with the correct set of Allow methods (in .htaccess, not the config)?

I have googled for a whole day, but searching for the keywords options and * is an exercise in futility, as you may imagine.

EDIT: For clarity, I will add that infrastructure methods such as `CONNECT` and `TRACE` are not passed on. I suspect `OPTIONS *` is in the same boat of requests that are handled before it even gets to the .htaccess, although it should not necessarily be, because the server doesn't know which methods are supported by scripts (hence why I want to specify them directly, if not in script then in the htaccess).